# Using require to establish communication between components in angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I want to create a communication between two components in angular 1.6. I have a navbar component that contains a search and a main component that contains a list that should be different depending on the search. I tried to use require to make this communication, but I received the following error

> Controller 'main', required by directive 'navbar', can't be found!

Here are the definitions of the components:

```
export default angular.module('directives.navbar', [])
  .component('navbar', {
    template: require('./navbar.html'),
    require: {
      mainCtrl: '^main'
    },
    controller: NavbarComponent
  })
  .name;


export default angular.module('licentaIonApp.main', [uiRouter])
  .config(routing)
  .component('main', {
    template: require('./main.html'),
    controller: MainController
  })
  .name;
```

What do you think the problem is? Is this the right way to communicate between two components?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to "communicate" between the two components? if you need to share state and/or functionality between two components, consider a using a `factory`.

Comment: actually i checked the docs and there is a whole section on this topic. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component -> scroll to the section titled "Intercomponent Communication"

Comment: Inter-component communication works based on the hierarchy, can you share the code where you are actually using these components?

Comment: I don't have any hierarchy between this two components